# How can I access columns by name in an anonymous data frame object for filtering in R?

Tags: r, aggregate, aggregate-functions, having, having-clause

I've got this one-liner:

```
aggregate(. ~ gear,mtcars[mtcars$mpg>20,c('gear','mpg')],mean)
```

Now I want to filter by mpg>25 like his:

```
aggregate(. ~ gear,mtcars[mtcars$mpg>20,c('gear','mpg')],mean)[mpg>25,]
```

But now I get some 1743 lines of `NA` entries

any ideas?

Comment: What object is `mpg`? I get "> aggregate(. ~ gear,mtcars[mtcars$mpg>20,c('gear','mpg')],mean)[mpg>25,]
Error in `[.data.frame`(aggregate(. ~ gear, mtcars[mtcars$mpg > 20, c("gear",  : 
  object 'mpg' not found" . Do you have anywhere `attach()` in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another solution with base functions:

```
subset(aggregate(. ~ gear,mtcars[mtcars$mpg>20,c('gear','mpg')],mean), mpg>25)
```

and here is a solution with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
M <- data.table(mtcars)
M[mpg>20, .(mpg=mean(mpg)), by=gear][mpg>25]
```

Answer (score 2):

A `dplyr` solution could be:

```
 mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% filter(mpg>25) %>% summarise(mean(mpg))
```

or rather:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% filter(mpg>20) %>% 
summarise(mean(mpg)) %>% filter(`mean(mpg)`>25)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't (and I don't get lots of `NA`s, I *correctly* get an error because `mpg` isn't found. Did you do something previously that allows `mpg` to be found?). R doesn't work the way you are trying to force it.

You will need

```
tmp <- aggregate(. ~ gear,
                 data = subset(mtcars, mpg > 20, select = c('gear','mpg')),
                 FUN = mean)
with(tmp, tmp[mpg > 25, ])

> with(tmp, tmp[mpg > 25, ])
  gear   mpg
2    4 25.74
3    5 28.20
```